# AWS autoscaling Lifecycle Terminating:Wait not working as I expected it to work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have recently setup ASG lifecycle hooks. So the ASG instances go into terminating:wait lifecycle state for 5 minutes and terminated automatically. But I observed that during the time the Instances are in Terminating:Wait new scale up activity is not being triggered. i.e Even though the trigger condition is satisfied, only after all the instances in Terminating:Wait state get terminated, does the desired value gets set. Is it because ASG looks for Healthy Instances ( since the Terminating:Wait instances will be in healthy state) ? Can someone please help me out with this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting the VPC while creating the Launch Configuration(LC) ,

Try creating LC with with out attaching the VPC and security group, and make sure you have selected the VPC in the ASG(Auto Scale Group)